# Prove that $(\partial X)\cap C\,\,\subseteq\,\,(\partial(X\cap C))\cup (\partial C)$ where $X$ is any not limited subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$...

Tags: general-topology

Prove that 
$$(\partial X)\cap C\,\,\subseteq\,\,(\partial(X\cap C))\cup (\partial C)$$  and
$$\partial(X\cap C)\,\,\subseteq\,\,((\partial X)\cap C)\cup (\partial C)$$ 
where $X$ is any not limited subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $(\partial X)\cap C\,\,\subseteq\,\,(\partial(X\cap C))\cup (\partial C)$: let $x\in (\partial X)\cap C$ then:$$x\in C=\bar{C}=\mathring{C}\cup\partial C$$ and $$x\in\partial X.$$ From $x\in\mathring{C}\,\,\rightarrow\,\,\exists B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq C$ where $\varepsilon>0.$ From $x\in \partial X\,\,\rightarrow\,\,B(x,\varepsilon)\cap X\neq \emptyset$ and $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus X)\neq\emptyset$.........????????

Comment: In fact you wish to prove that  $((\partial X)\cap C)\Delta \partial(X\cap C)\subseteq \partial C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for any subset $A$ of any topological space $T$ we have $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus\operatorname{int} A$ is a set of points $x$ of the space $T$ such that each neighborhood $O_x$ of the point $x$ contains points both from $A$ and $T\setminus A$.

Both inclusions can be proved for any (not necessarily unbounded) subset $X$ and any closed subset $C$ of any topological space $T$.

Let $x$ be an arbitrary point of the set $(\partial X)\cap C$. Let $O_x$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of the point $x$. Then $O_x$ contains a point from the set $T\setminus X\subset T\setminus (X\cap C)$. If $x\not\in \partial C$ then $x\in\operatorname{int} C$. Therefore $O_x\cap \operatorname{int} C$ is a neighborhood of the point $x$, so it contains a point $y\in X$. Then $y\in X\cap \operatorname{int} C\cap O_x \subset X\cap C\cap O_x$. Thus $x\in \partial(X\cap C)$.

Let $x$ be an arbitrary point of the set $\partial(X\cap C)$. Then $x\in\overline{X\cap C }\subset\overline C=C$.  Let $O_x$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of the point $x$. Then $O_x$ contains a point of the set $X$. If $x\not\in \partial C$ then $x\in\operatorname{int} C$. Therefore $O_x\cap \operatorname{int} C$ is a neighborhood of the point $x$, so it contains a point $y\in T\setminus (X\cap C)$. Then $y\in ((T\setminus X)\cup (T\setminus C))\cap \operatorname{int} C\cap O_x \subset (T\setminus X)\cap O_x$. Thus $x\in (\partial X)\cap C$.

Answer (score 1):

I pursue your reasoning in the comment above. If $x\in\partial C$, then $x\in (\partial(X\cap C))\cup \partial C$.

Now, assume $x\notin \partial C$: then $x\in \mathring{C}$ and, fixing $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq C$, what you wrote shows that $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (X\cap C)\neq \varnothing$. 
Now, $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (\Bbb R^n\setminus(X\cap C))=B(x,\varepsilon)\cap ((\Bbb R^n\setminus X)\cup (\Bbb R^n\setminus C))=(B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (\Bbb R^n\setminus X))\cup (B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (\Bbb R^n\setminus C) \neq \varnothing$ since $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (\Bbb R^n\setminus X)\neq \varnothing$.

Hence, $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (X\cap C)\neq \varnothing$ and $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap (\Bbb R^n\setminus(X\cap C))\neq \varnothing$, i.e. $x\in \partial(X\cap C)\subseteq
  (\partial(X\cap C))\cup \partial C$.